# network + ui updates, asynctask vs handler

Tags: android

I have a map that i want to update from a separate thread. Im having some issues when i try to update the UI from my class that extends asynctask. And when i move the code to a handler in the main thread i get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Below is my asynctask. Is there any way to modify it to make it work?

```
@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://83.xx.xx:8080/android/service.php");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "getusers"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("interval", Integer.toString(interval)));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>() {}.getType();
            ArrayList<User> userList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);

            ((GoogleMapsActivity) activity).removeOverlayItems();

            for(User user : userList ){

                ((GoogleMapsActivity) activity).addOverlayItem(Double.parseDouble(user.last_lat), Double.parseDouble(user.last_lng), user.bluetooth_name, "test desc");
            }


            return 1;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than touching the map in your doInBackground, return your data into onPostExecute. Then update the map from onPostExecute.

Please note that you should never retain a reference to your Activity from inside your AsyncTask or you could cause a memory leak.

Ideally, you should create an observer that can return data to your Activity.

```
interface Observer {
    public void onMyDataAvailable(MyDataClass data);
}
```

Then, you instantiate your AsyncTask with a reference to this observer.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask ...
    private Observer observer;

    public MyAsyncTask(Observer observer) {
        mObserver = observer;
    }

    public synchronized void onActivityDestroyed() {
        mObserver = null;
    }

    public synchronized void onPostExecute(MyDataClass result) {
        if (mObserver != null) {
            mObserver.onMyDataAvailable(result);
        }
    }
```

Just make sure you call onActivityDestroyed() from your activity's onDestroy method. Otherwise your Activity will leak.

Comment: Allright, thanks for answering. Could you show me an example on how to fetch the data from the asynctask to the main thread?

Comment: Thanks a lot. What would happen if i just pass my userlist as the return value and use `task.execute.get()` in the main thread, and then update the ui in the same thread? Bad idea? :)

Comment: Yeah, bad idea. The reason is that the object you are editing with your user list is inside your Activity. The rule is that you should not edit your Activity after it has been destroyed. That's why you should return to your observer, and allow your Activity to kill your observer if it is being destroyed.

Comment: Ok, and a final question: Why cant i just create a public property in my main activity (ArrayList<User>) in this case, and update it from the `onPostExecute`?

Comment: Because if your activity is "destroyed" by the system, it will not be garbage collected until after onPostExecute finishes. This is a memory leak.

Comment: Hmm, i cant seem to get the data in my main thread. Im not very familiar with interfaces obviously. If you got time, please show me a snippet on how to do that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13088/discussion-between-windyb-and-johan)

Comment: I gave it another shot today and it worked like a charm :) Thanks for the help!